# Pull record from one table store in another table with additional data

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am pulling records from one table into another like this

```vb
strsql = strsql & " INSERT INTO Activity (noteKey, originalNoteEmp, originalNoteDate, data)" &
    "SELECT NoteKey, UserName, NoteDate, Notes " & 
    "FROM dbo.Note " & 
    "WHERE NoteKey = " & lngNoteKey
```

My question is, how can I add additional data to be inserted into the table if the data isn't inside of the orginal table it is data which is derived from the application it self. I.e. additional variables.

Is there a way to add it to this command?

Comment: The insert isn't concerned with whether its data came from a table or not, as long as your selected row contains the same number of columns and the datatypes match, you're fine. If you need to add values to your select, you can just concatenate them in like " select col1, col2, col3, col4, 'xtraVal1', 'xtraVal2' from table "

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have 2 fields - *id* and *name*. In your project you need to insert them into table but *id* comes from another table and *name* comes from application

```vb
sql = "INSERT INTO tbl1 (id, name) select (id, '" & txtbox.Text & "') FROM tbl2..."
```

I think, this will give you an idea and you can work from here.

Of course, if you inserting multiple records, you will have to go row-by-row.